# NSMutableArray resets itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm performing some basic operations on two mutable arrays. However, the program behaves strangely. The second array resets itself after a function ends.

First, I allocate memory for the two arrays. I then populate `originalArray` with numbers from 0..10.

My code looks like this.

ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *originalArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondArray;
```

ViewController.c

```
static int level=1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self firstArrayInit];
    [self secondArrayInit];

    [self startDisplaying];

}

-(void) firstArrayInit{
    self.originalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        [self.originalArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }

}

-(void)secondArrayInit{
    self.secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

-(void) startDisplaying{ 
        NSLog(@"Initial Array is %@", self.originalArray);

        self.mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(displayNumber)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
        NSLog(@"SecondA: %@", self.secondArray); //prints EMPTY ARRAY!!


}

-(void) displayNumber{
    static int num=0;
   NSLog(@"Num: %d", num);
   NSLog(@"Level: %d", level);

    if (num < level){
        //display on a label
        myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.originalArray objectAtIndex:num]];
        [self addToSecondArray:num];
        num++;
        NSLog(@"SecondA: %@", self.secondArray); //prints the contents of Array FINE!!

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"SecondA2: %@", self.secondArray); //PRINTS EMPTY ARRAY!!
    }
}

-(void)addToSecondArray:(int)myNumber{
    [self.secondArray addObject:[self.originalArray objectAtIndex:myNumber]];

}
```

Outputs:

```
Initial Array is (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9
)

Num: 0
Level: 1

SecondA: (
    0
)

Num:1
Level: 1

SecondA2: (
)
```

Comment: This code is completely useless alone. Publish the whole code with the call to `startDisplaying`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWill/DidAppear`, etc.

Comment: Show us the declarations.

Comment: It would be empty in `startDisplaying` because `displayNumber` hasn't been called yet.

Comment: I guess your problem is that `SecondA2` should not be empty? What is the value of `level`? What is the output of the app (the order the output occurs is also important)?

Comment: It would be empty in `displayNumber` if `level` is zero.

Comment: I setup a test project with your code. Its working and the second array never becomes empty. I think you should provide your full code.

Comment: It was working fine before the new Xcode update. I'm using Xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: You are accessing the `NSMutableArray` from multiple threads and `NSMutableArray` is not thread-safe.

Comment: See here to add breakpoints to see when your variable is changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150221/how-do-i-have-a-breakpoint-get-triggered-if-an-instance-variable-in-the-class-ha

Comment: Besides i reproduced your code and it runs. Error has to come from somewhere else which you did not provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code above and get different output from what you are showing. Are you running this on a device? Perhaps the device has an old version of the build?

Here is the out I am getting and the `secondArray` looks fine. As expected by the timer, the last three lines of logging repeat every two seconds.

Something else that seems odd in your output is that the very first logging of the `SecondA` value is missing.

```
2014-10-11 07:29:05.419 test[58826:1475246] Initial Array is (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9
)
2014-10-11 07:29:05.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA: (
)
2014-10-11 07:29:07.420 test[58826:1475246] Num: 0
2014-10-11 07:29:07.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:07.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA: (
    0
)
2014-10-11 07:29:09.420 test[58826:1475246] Num: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:09.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:09.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA2: (
    0
)
2014-10-11 07:29:11.420 test[58826:1475246] Num: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:11.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:11.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA2: (
0
)
2014-10-11 07:29:13.419 test[58826:1475246] Num: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:13.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:13.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA2: (
    0
)
2014-10-11 07:29:15.419 test[58826:1475246] Num: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:15.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:15.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA2: (
    0
)
2014-10-11 07:29:17.419 test[58826:1475246] Num: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:17.420 test[58826:1475246] Level: 1
2014-10-11 07:29:17.420 test[58826:1475246] SecondA2: (
    0
)
```

Comment: I'm running it on the simulator. It was working fine before I updated my Xcode to the new version (6.0.1).

Comment: Definitely seems to be an issue with your environment, not your code.

Comment: After a little debugging, I found that there was a broken link between two view controllers.